# Error apache2 after enable virtual host

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Hello could anyone tell me what's problem about apache2?
after I create a virtual host then I just enable it as this command line in ubuntu "sudo a2ensite dev.codeigniter.com.conf" and the file contant "

```
ServerAdmin pkayjava@gmail.com

DocumentRoot /opt/php/dev.codeigniter.com
ServerName dev.codeigniter.com

AssignUserID visalthorn socheat

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.codeigniter.com-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dev.codeigniter.com-access.log combined
```

".
then I have to restart apache2 by this command line "sudo service apache2 restart" and it show error like this "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details." I try to enable other virtual host and it happens the same error. thanks

Comment: Try running `sudo journalctl -xe` for more information on what's causing the issue. Possible duplicate on another site: [Apache not able to restart](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

to see if you have any configuration errors.

See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart